# Fetch only matched array object from a list of available array objects with MongoTemplate and Query API

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a scenario where i pass a parameters to a collection in MongoDB and fetch only that particular array object **serviceType** which matched my criteria *"serviceType"= Repairs & Fixes*.

**Collection Sample**

```
"serviceTypes": [
        {
            "serviceType": "Installation/Uninstallation Service",
        },
        {
            "serviceType": "Repairs & Fixes",
        },
        {
            "serviceType": "Electricity Breakdown",
        },
        {
            "serviceType": "Electricity Wiring",
        }
    ]
```

As per my implementation below, it fetches all the array objects instead of that particular array object. The above collection sample is the actual response for the below code.

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
@Override
public ServiceList findOneByServiceType(String categoryName, String 
serviceType1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Query query = new Query() ;
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("categoryName").is(categoryName).andOperator(Criteria.where("serviceTypes").elemMatch(Criteria.where("serviceType").is(serviceType1))));
    query.fields().include("serviceTypes.serviceType");
    return (ServiceList) mongoTemplate.findOne(query,ServiceList.class);
}
```

How to handle this scenario with mongotemplate and Query api of Spring boot Mongo?

Comment: Have you tried using elemMatch in a projection?

Comment: No. I am new to mongoDb and so querying through java. Guide me if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to replace this line

```
query.fields().include("serviceTypes.serviceType");
```

with the below line

```
query.fields().include("serviceTypes").position("serviceTypes",1);
```